# How to authorize WCF hosted on public http server to certain clients

Tags: web-services, wcf, authentication, authorization, wshttpbinding

A web service hosted on a http public server need to be authorized to only to be consumed by specific clients developed/controlled by us. There are no role based authorization. Some of the specifics about the service.

The web service hosted on http web server currently uses basicHttpBinding but we plan to use wsHttpBinding with certification authentication and message security, this service is consumed on multiple client machines by Windows Services (services also build on WCF and published using netTcp binding to be consumed by WPF applications). We want to authorize only those windows services to able to consume the web services.

There is no role/indentity based authorization in this scenario.

What is out of the box authorization that WCF provides that can be applicable in my scenario?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: sorry edited the question.

Comment: It sounds like you want authentication for only certain clients. And not authorization? 
In that case your decision to use message security with certificates sounds like a good place to start.

Comment: Yes but that would only give me message level security, anybody with any WCF client can still access the service and manipulate/access data, which is what we are trying to restrict.